# Questions about Git

Tags: git

Operation steps:

1. I changed the solid-state drive for the computer and reinstalled the    system
2. I put the original solid state The SSH folder is completely copied to the new solid-state system
3. I pulled the code on gitlab and found an error

I want to know why. Judging from the reasons for the error, it seems that git has not read the contents of host and port at all, but I don't know. From the verification of my guess, I want to know how to solve my current problem

git pull errMsg：

> Network error: Connection timed out
> Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
> kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists

Comment: This doesn't seem like a git specific issue

Comment: Please edit the question to focus on what you are doing and the error you are getting with relevant info. For example why is it using port 65535 - is that correct? Adding your git config to the question would help.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the remote URL of the local repository from which you are pulling your remote GitLab repository.

```bash
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote -v
```

Make sure it actually is an SSH URL like `git@gitlab.com:you/yourProject`.

Check also if you have a `~/.ssh/config` file with a Host entry which would involve your target GitLab remote server.

Finally, a [`kex_exchange_identification`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_2/kex.c#L1168) error is (from [mforsetti](https://serverfault.com/users/202575/mforsetti)'s [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1015554/783))  a function to exchange server and client identification (duh), and the [specified error](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_2/kex.c#L1247) happened if the socket connection between OpenSSH server and client is interrupted ([see EPIPE](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html)), i.e. client already closed its connection.

Depending on your OS and the target GitLab (gitlab.com or on-premise GitLab), you will need to check your remote server (on-premise GitLab)  `openssh-server` settings, port, VPN if you are using it, port translation  at a load-balancer...